# How to define return type using keyof accessor with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, casting

Is it possible to create a function that uses `keyof` to access a property of an object, and have TypeScript infer the return value?

```js
interface Example {
    name: string;
    handles: number;
}

function get(n: keyof Example) {
   const x: Example = {name: 'House', handles: 8};
   return x[n];
}

function put(value: string) {

}

put(get("name"));
// ^^^ Error: Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

TypeScript is *merging* all the allowed types together, but when the function is called with the value `"name"` it does not infer the type is `string`.

I can resolve the issue by casting the type.

```js
put(get("name") as string);
```

Is there a way to do this without casting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you just have to make `get` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) so that it doesn't return the union of all possible output types:

```
function get<K extends keyof Example>(n: K) {
  const x: Example = { name: "House", handles: 8 };
  return x[n];
}
```

Now the signature is inferred to be:

```
// function get<K extends "name" | "handles">(n: K): Example[K]
```

Where the return type, `Example[K]`, is a [lookup type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) representing the type you get when you index into an `Example` with key `K`.

When you call it, `K` is inferred to be a string literal type if it can be:

```
get("name"); // function get<"name">(n: "name"): string
```

And `Example["name"]` is equivalent to `string`.  So now your call works as desired:

```
put(get("name")); // okay
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChlkRsIAuZAZzClAHMBuU5ACzhABMDaaIAK5YARtDYBfYsRhCQCMMAD2IZEwhgAPAGlkEdJF61kAawgBPZTDSZcBAHwAKEDR0BKZCTIJV9ZOg0GNj4KAC8XuSUNABEABLKQrQQMQA0nNx8EALIABzIkmxkUJpCUGroANogALpSxAD0DchyCkqq6pq6+oYQxsgxFFgpyAA+A1y8-DHOrsgeQXahlTo1Mq2KKmo4QmBOAG5weELUdAzMnoTSxBp7g5Qx7izITS3ymx23WvfDMy6xQxS7ho9EYICYMh2e1uTh+QKeL2aylMcAsxCAA)